# Sitecore Lucene: re-index child (or parent) items on updating item

Tags: database, lucene, indexing, sitecore, web-crawler

**Situation**

I have the following Sitecore Lucene config:

- New index, type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel"
- Contains two crawlers (a custom crawler that adds extra "calculated" fields)
- Each crawler handles its specific template GUID, because they contain different calculated fields

**Problem**

The calculated fields are based on *parent/child* fields. How Lucene in Sitecore seems to be set up, is that only the documents for the *items that were actually changed* are updated in the index.

As such, the calculated fields on other documents (which are required, there are search conditions on these fields) are not updated.

**Question**

Is there a possibility to manually trigger the update of other items in the index?
I've looked into inheriting Sitecore.Search.Index, but none of the relevant methods are virtual.

Also, I tried to subscribe to the IndexingProvider-events:
public event EventHandler OnRemoveItem;
public event EventHandler OnRemoveVersion;
public event EventHandler OnUpdateItem;

The idea behind this was to trigger the OnUpdateItem-event in the DatabaseCrawler for other items that need to be updated, but you can't trigger this event from outside the IndexingProvider.

Is there a way to trigger an index update without doing a full rebuild, that does not involve saving/republishing those other items?

Thanks!
Sander

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Index update is triggered via the HistoryEngine, whose events and methods are public, so you could potentially utilize an event handler on the history engine to detect when a change occurs that requires reindexing, and then add additional entries to the history for the parent/child items you need to reindex as well.

`Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingManager.InitializeEventHandlers()` has an example of attaching a handler to the `HistoryEngine` of the databases.

Then your handler logic would be something like

```
protected void HistoryEngine_AddedEntry(object sender, HistoryAddedEventArgs e)
{
    Item item = e.Database.GetItem(e.Entry.ItemId);
    //TODO: Add logic to make sure e.Entry.ItemId requires a parent/child reindex as well
    //TODO: Make sure that logic also prevents excessive or infinite recursion since we'll be triggering the AddedEntry event again below
    Item parent = item.Parent;
    //RegisterItemSaved doesn't appear to do anything with its second argument
    e.Database.Engines.HistoryEngine.RegisterItemSaved(parent, null);
}
```

The best place to attach this is probably in the `initialize` pipeline.

N.B. this is an untested idea, please report back on your results!

Comment: Won't triggering the HistoryEngine with additional entries have any adverse side effects on other Sitecore components?
It does sound like a reasonable approach, so I'll try this soon. I'll report back soon, first need to finish some other sprint tasks ;)

Comment: Analysis in reflector shows IndexingManager as the only listener for HistoryEngine.AddedEntry, so you're probably safe there. Can't guarantee whether it's future proof in that respect, I suppose. That said, it does bring up a point that your AddedEntry listener needs to have logic to prevent infinite recursion. Will edit.